# Capture mouse position outside of a chrome app window

Tags: google-chrome-app

Is it possible to capture the mouse position outside of a chrome app window?

Could this be achieved by using a transparent window to capture the mouse position?

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve? Place a mouse move listener on the window and you will have implicit mouse capture for the duration of any mouse drag. See [image edit sample](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/image-edit), [app.js](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/image-edit/app.js).